# Displaying gathered tweets using R to a php web application

Tags: r

I have created a simple web application using PHP to display gathered tweets. I am using Rstudio to understand about R programming and successfully gathered tweets using R.
I am able to gather tweets and save them in a .csv format

Now the problem is, I need to integrate my R code with php web application

In my php form I have a input button named gather data to gather tweets and I'm using shell_exec("Rscript filename.R") to call R from PHP.

When I click on the button it executes and returns [1] using direct Authentication and stops, but no csv file is returned. When I execute directly from terminal as Rscript filename.R csv file is returned. HTML button type is submit, name is b1 and value is Gather Data

PHP

```
    if(isset($_POST['b1'])){
        $output = shell_exec("Rscript filename.R $b1");
        echo $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are passing the arguments in the quotes
Do the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['b1'])){
    $output = shell_exec("Rscript filename.R ".$b1);
    echo $output;
}
```